# Complex Joins in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

It's possible I'm stupid, but I've been querying and checking for hours and I can't seem to find the answer to this, so I apologize in advance if the post is redundant... but I can't seem to find its doppelganger.

OK:  I have a PostGreSQL db with the following tables:

Key(containing two fields in which I'm interested, ID and Name)
and a second table, Key.

Data contains well... data, sorted by ID.  ID is unique, but each Name has multiple ID's.  E.G. if Bill enters the building this is ID 1 for Bill.  Mary enters the building, ID 2 for Mary, Bill re-enters the building, ID 3 for Bill.

The ID field is in both the Key table, and the DATA table.

What I want to do is... find

The MAX (e.g. last) ID, unique to EACH NAME, and the Data associated with it.

E.g. `Bill - Last Login: ID 10.  Time: 123UTC  Door: West` and so on.

So... I'm trying the following query:

```
SELECT
 *
FROM 
  Data, Key
WHERE 
  Key.ID = ( 
    SELECT 
      MAX (ID)
    FROM 
      Key
    GROUP BY ID
)
```

Here's the kicker, there's about... something like 800M items in these tables, so errors are... time consuming.  Can anyone help to see if this query is gonna do what I expect?

Thanks so much.

Comment: `FROM Data, Key` will cause a carthesian product. Do you *really* want that ?

Comment: Hm, no. 
Again I'm just trying to find the very last ID for each unique Name, with an implicit join of the two tables.  My brain is -smoking-.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the maximum key for each name . . .

```
select Name, max(ID) as max_id
from data
group by Name;
```

Join that to your other table.

```
select *
from key t1
inner join (select Name, max(ID) as max_id
            from data
            group by Name) t2
on t1.id = t2.max_id
```

Comment: Ok, one more... is there a way to do this as one big-ass query? There's a third thing that's like Activity ID.  

So like... Name -> ID -> Activity 
Getting only the LAST Activity in the LAST ID for each unique name... 

Sorry to be a pain - there's a -lot- of data here, and it's clear you're a lot more versed in these complex queries :\

Comment: Probably. Copy the CREATE TABLE statements for your tables from pgAdminIII, and paste them into your question.

Comment: Actually, I think what you've got here works. 
I'm gonna toss in an Order By Random Limit 1000 to get a representative sample.  Thanks so much :)